# Trying to add 1 to current field value with MySQL, but can't figure out what's wrong with my syntax

Tags: sql, mysql

I'm hoping someone can spot my mistake in this MySQL query.

```
UPDATE 'databasename'.'tablename' 
   SET fieldB = fieldB + 1 
 WHERE fieldA = '2';
```

I'm basically trying to add 1 to the current value of fieldB where fieldA is i.e 2.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

[Single-quotes are for strings](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-syntax.html).

```
UPDATE `databasename`.`tablename` 
SET fieldB = fieldB + 1 
WHERE fieldA = '2';
```

You can use backticks around the database and tablenames; they aren't strictly necessary though.

Comment: +1, but worth mentioning that backticks are necessary if any of your databases, tables or fields use reserved words.