# i would like to make a like button, but this is doesn't work php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, button

this is my code but it does not work I want a code that makes a like button for every img and if they press a button the need for waarde + 1 is to be done. but why does this code not work, he connects it well with the database but he does not do anything waarde +1

what he is doing now he increases the value of the first row in the database and it does not matter which button you click

```
$sql="SELECT url, categorie FROM url";
if ($result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql))
{
    while ($row=mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
        $url = $row[0];
?>
         <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-3 isotope-item <?php echo $row[1]; ?>">
             <div class="image-gallery-item mb-4 pb-3">
                 <a href="<?php echo $row[0]; ?>" class="lightbox-portfolio">
                     <span class="thumb-info custom-thumb-info-1">
                         <span class="thumb-info-wrapper">
                             <span class="thumb-info-plus"></span>
                             <img src="<?php echo $row[0]; ?>" class="img-fluid" alt="">
                            <form action="" method="POST"> 
                                <button type="submit" value="<?php echo $url;?>" class="btn-floating  waves-effect waves-dark transparent" name="like">
                                    <i class="material-icons blue-text">thumb_up</i>
                                </button>
                            </form>

                         </span>
                     </span>
                 </a>
             </div>
         </div>                          

<?php 
}

    if(isset($_POST['like'])){
        $sql = "UPDATE url SET waarde = waarde + 1 WHERE url = '".$url."'";

        if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
            echo "Record updated successfully";
        } else {
            echo "Error updating record: " . $conn->error;
        }
        $conn->close();
    } 

    mysqli_free_result($result);
} 
mysqli_close($connection); 
?>
```

can somebody help me?

Comment: Check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4330805/trying-to-add-1-to-current-field-value-with-mysql-but-cant-figure-out-whats-w

Comment: This code makes little sense to begin with, working with the POSTed value should not happen inside your while loop in the first place. Used a fixed name for the buttons, and put the value you need to send into the `value` attribute of the button.

Comment: @misorude yes i know but even then he does not work.

Comment: Even with your edit, that part is still inside the while loop - fix that. And right now you are not submitting any value at all - where is the `value` attribute on the button element?

Comment: @misorude but if I do this he always does it only at the last and it does not matter which button you click

Comment: Well it would matter, if you gave the button a _value_, as I have now told you several times already. (And then you use that value in your update query, not your $url variable.)

Comment: @misorude how can I do that best than what I do not understand

Comment: What don’t you understand? Be specific.

Comment: @misorude how i can use that value in my update query

Comment: You have access to it via `$_POST['like']`. Right now, you are not sending a value that makes sense though - you got the _same_ `value="like"` for all your buttons. _That_ is the place where your $url belongs.

Comment: @misorude and then what do i need to do with my query

Comment: Well use the value that is inside `$_POST['like']` …

Comment: @misorude So what exactly do I have to do to get it working

Comment: You will have to fix your broken HTML first. You can not put a `form` into a `span`, and more important, you can not put an interactive element like a form into a link. The automatic error correction the browser has to apply due to these mistakes has likely messed up the resulting DOM structure too bad for this to properly work. Suggestion: Take all the formatting, linking, applying of external functionality like isotope out of it for now. Make this a list of divs that contain nothing but the actual image, and the form - and test with that first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this:

```
if(isset($_POST['like'])){
        $sql = "UPDATE url SET waarde = waarde + 1 WHERE url = '".$url."'";
```

into this:

```
if(isset($_POST['like'])){
        $value = $_POST['like'];
        $sql = "UPDATE url SET waarde = waarde + 1 WHERE url = '$value'";
```

so you are parametrizing your query to the url that have been posted.

Two side notes:

- the update query should be out of the while loop. It is not necessary to repeat it several times;
- you should not have the same name for a table (url) and a field in the table (url). It is not a good practice at least for readibility and can lead to issues in the query if you don't specify always the table name like `url.url`